# Running a stored procedure using a resultset as the parameter and insert into a table

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql, cursors

I have the question below,

I do have a query which returns 10 rows for example.

```
SELECT CarId FROM Car 

EXEC spQ_GetCar (@CarId)
```

Also, I have a stored procedure that uses an id from the table above.

My question is, how can I run the stored procedure and use the output of the table as the parameter and then insert that into another temp table.

Would it be possible by using a cursor and dynamic SQL ?, has anyone faced this before ?

**NOTES**: I cannot create a table type to use it

Comment: If you want to pass a dataset to a procedure, use a table type parameter. You can't pass a `SELECT` to a procedure as a parameter. Otherwise, yes, you could use a `CURSOR` and run the procedure once for *each* row, however, it would be much less performant.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does `spQ_GetCar` do? It matters. Stored procedures aren't functions in a procedural language. SQL isn't a procedural language. If you want to combine queries, use a VIEW, a subquery or a CTE. In some cases you can use an inline table-valued function to act as a parameterized view. What you try to do is probably the worst option

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its a complex procedure with more nested stored procedures, table functions etc.

Looking to simplify if possible.

Comment: What you try to do right now is try to reverse how SQL works. Instead of trying to feed the output of one query or stored procedure to the next, combine them. Combining may mean nesting one operation inside another, or *joining* two different results.

Answer (score 0):

A fast answer:

Create a table, then you can `insert-exec`:

```
insert yourPreparedtable
EXEC spQ_GetCar (@CarId)
```

The true answer:

[Erland Sommarskog's article](https://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) is the most in-depth resource you will find. Many alternatives with detailed advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by following approach below:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (CarId INT)

DECLARE @CarId INT

DECLARE Car CURSOR
    ,CarId INT SET Car = CURSOR STATIC
FOR
SELECT CarId
FROM Car

OPEN Car

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH Car
    INTO @CarId

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK

    INSERT INTO #TEMP
    EXEC spQ_GetCar(@CarId)
END

CLOSE @ServiceAgreements

DEALLOCATE @ServiceAgreements

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Notes: Performance was not relevant as it was a one off script.